# Наследуется приватное свойство

Tags: php

Почему унаследованный класс получает доступ к приватному свойству базового класса?

Не должно же такого быть.

Ну и что, что parent указан, всё равно такого не должно быть.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

class ShopProduct{

    private $price;

    public function __construct ($price){
        $this->price = $price;
    }
    public function getPrice(){
        return $this->price;
    }
}

class BookProduct extends ShopProduct{
    public function getPrice(){
        return parent::getPrice() . $this->price;
    }
}
$product1 = new BookProduct(10.40);

echo $product1->getPrice();
```

Comment: Чего именно не должно быть? Вы в конструкторе явно задаете значение `$this->price`

Comment: а если убрать parent::getPrice() то работать не будет

Comment: дак убрать и будет пусто, ибо доступа нет. А оставить, дак вернется то что в коснтрукторе указано, а не то что `$this->price`, оно так и останется недоступным (пустым)

Comment: то есть в строке `return parent::getPrice() . $this->price;` всю работу выполняет `parent::getPrice()`, а последняя часть (`$this->price`)всегда не работает. Так что убираете начало - будет пустота, оставите - будут полученные от родительского класса данные.

Answer (score 5):

**Что происходит?**

Ваш код отлично [работает и выводит](https://3v4l.org/5INc2) строку

> 10.4

А еще, он выдает вам вот такое замечание:

> Notice: Undefined property: BookProduct::$price in xxx on line 17

**Что на самом деле происходит?**

Вот тут

```
return parent::getPrice() . $this->price;
```

вы вызываете метод `ShopProduct::getPrice` (публичный метод базового класса), и пытаетесь получить значение поля `BookProduct::$price` (поле текущего класса).

Метод `ShopProduct::getPrice` возвращает цену из конструктора, а `BookProduct::$price` - не определено, поэтому принимает значение `null` и приводится к пустой строке.

Неудивительно, что вместо двух цен подряд (`10.410.4`) на выходе вы получаете всего одну цену и предупреждение об обращении к неопределенному полю.

Как вы уже догадались, ограничение области видимости работает отлично, и никто не даст вам получить значение `private` поля в дочернем классе.

---

Чтобы не попадать в таки недоразумения, достаточно внимательно читать все ошибки, предупреждения и замечания, что выдает вам PHP. В них содержится намного больше информации, чем вы можете себе представить.

Comment: _удвоенной цены_ звучит как `20.8` а не `10.410.4` :)

Comment: Действительно. Исправил